# How to convert between vector_float2 and CGPoint*?

Tags: objective-c, vector, type-conversion, cgpoint, xcode7

What's the easiest/fastest way to convert between vector_float2 and CGPoint* in Objective-C?

Does Apple provide any built-in functionality for this kind of type conversion? I noticed in 2-3 places in sample apps they just call CGPointMake() etc. to make the conversion

Is it possible to simply cast a CGPoint* to vector_float2 and vice versa? Is it safe to do so?

---

Update: obviously the solution is:

```
vector_float2 v = (vector_float2){(float)point.x, (float)point.y};
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(v.x, v.y);
```

But this is cumbersome if you need to do so frequently, and more so if there's a C array of either `vector_float2*` or `CGPoint*`. So I'm looking for already-existing solutions or very simple alternatives that I may be overlooking.

Comment: What about writing a function CGPointMakeFromFloat2 ?

Comment: Yes, that option exists of course. But I wonder if there's already something built in somehow somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to simply extend `CGPoint` but couldnt seem to import `vector_float2`; not even with the bridging header file.

```
// Doesn't work!!
extension CGPoint {
    init(vector: vector_float2)
    {
        self.x = CGFloat(vector.x)
        self.y = CGFloat(vector.y)
    }
}
```

You do have several options though. You can extend `Float` with a calculated `var` that returns a `CGFloat` and extend `GKAgent2D` to convert it's position to a `CGPoint`:

```
extension Float {
    var f: CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}

extension GKAgent2D {
    var cgposition: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.position.x.f, y: self.position.y.f)
    }
}
```

You can also extend `CGPoint` itself to accept two `Float`'s:

```
extension CGPoint {
    init(x: Float, y: Float) {
        self.x = CGFloat(x)
        self.y = CGFloat(y)
    }
}

extension GKAgent2D {
    var cgposition: CGPoint {
         // Note that the ".f" is gone from the example above
        return CGPoint(x: self.position.x, y: self.position.y)
    }
}
```

In both cases, you can use it like this:

```
let agent = GKAgent2D()
let point = agent.cgposition
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the Objective-C tag. But nice example for encapsulating the conversion within the types.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
CGPoint p                   = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
vector_float2 v             = simd_make_float2(p.x, p.y);
CGPoint x                   = CGPointMake(v[0], v[1]);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me